# Good homework questions: answer with hints or full answers?

Tags: discussion, homework

When a homework question is properly formed and includes an attempt at a solution what is the recommended way to answer?

- Provide a full and complete answer
- Provide guidance or hints that will lead the student to a better solution

I have my own opinion of course but I'd like to know the policy.  Or at least the SO communities opinion.

I recently faced this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28687775/loops-when-user-input-is-wrong-and-increments-when-input-is-right) and decided not to copy and paste my solution into the answer and instead recommended a different way to think about the problem and offered some code snippets.

This is the kind of thing I did back when I was a CS tutor.  When I answer this way I feel there is less of a risk that the student will end up learning nothing or blindly copy the answer and get accused of plagiarism.

If there is anything official about this issue please refer me to it.

Comment: You can find a good bit on this subject on meta if you look. There're different camps on those two issues or allowing homework questions at all. Pick a side; or don't.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I've searched thru many meta homework questions. Most of them are about bad questions not good questions. I'm not asking if they should be allowed. I'm asking about how best to answer the good ones.  Didn't find anything about that.

Comment: It would be nice if these downvotes came with an explanation.

Comment: It's not clear what "issue" you're referring to. Was there something wrong with that post? Homework questions shouldn't be looked at any differently so treat it like a good normal question. Simply pointing someone in the right direction is sufficient per policy.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I am asking for an opinion of what is best.   What I'm hearing is "just follow the rules and you can do what you want".  While this is true, it is not helpful.

Comment: There is no special policy for homework questions and their answers - they simply need to be well-formulated, on-topic and useful to future readers. I'm curious to know what the community's opinion is though.

Comment: see also [feeding them vs. teaching to fish](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32716/165773) at MSE

Answer (score 4):

I'm very curious to see what the general view is as well. To get the activity started, and give people a chance to vote, I'll put a stake in the ground.

In my opinion, you should answer them, just like any other question. This means that they should be answered fully and in detail where possible. My main reasons for this point of view:

1. The goal of this site is to build a repository of questions and answers. Just because it was homework for the OP doesn't mean that future readers will be in the same situation. They don't expect to find intentionally obscured hints as answers. They expect real answers.
2. While it's sometimes obvious that a question is homework, it would be fairly easy to disguise it if somebody wanted. Should we punish the posters who present it as what it is, and reward the ones who try to hide the true motivation of the question? I don't think we should.
3. To me it's in the nature of homework that you can get any help you want. It doesn't make a difference if that's a web search, asking somebody in person, copying the solution from a fellow student, or asking on SO. It's all the same thing. Homework is an opportunity to learn and practice. If somebody does not want to take full advantage of that, it's their own choice. They will probably pay the price at exam time, but getting the best possible preparation for their exams is everybody's own responsibility.

If there needs to be a place for getting gentle hints on homework, it should be a separate site. SO does not seem like the right place for it.

I have seen the types of questions that you're asking about, which were actually interesting problems, but clearly originated in homework. Once others started posting hints, I was worried that I would violate an unwritten rule if I answered them. It's frustrating because if I see a question that interests me, I want to answer. If I can't, it shouldn't be posted in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

> I have my own opinion of course but I'd like to know the policy. Or at
>   least the SO communities opinion.

I think it's been well established here that there's no specific policy towards answers for homework questions so adhering to the help center's [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) would be the default. That is essentially it is up to you to decide and the community to judge as long as you *at least* pointed the asker in the right direction.

As far as the opinion part, I think it's a bit easier than you may be thinking. A good homework question shouldn't *need* an exhaustive solution. IME, a "good" student will say "I don't want the code..."; others may not but either way a question that requires a ton of code isn't really that good. IMHO, the question you linked to is *not* a good question in general. It's not much better than a requirement + code dump and a debug request. x-number lines of code doesn't quantify goodness.

> When I answer this way I feel there is less of a risk that the student
>   will end up learning nothing or blindly copy the answer and get
>   accused of plagiarism.

This is beyond my concern in general. For one, that "risk" isn't mine; I'm more of a personal responsibility kind of guy. If a student doesn't learn anything that's unequivocally *their* fault - grappy professors and any other complaints included. And I surely am not responsible for someone's personal academic integrity. I'm a student myself, SO has helped me learn far more than it's hindered it; granted I no longer use it for homework specific questions.

Bottom line is when I answer a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20085016/self-organizing-search-program-java-homework/20085991#20085991) I judge it and answer how *I* see fit based on what I get from the post - attitude, effort, previous community activity, etc. And I [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28398144/basic-visual-studio-2013-programming/28398225#28398225) *a* specific question, not debug their hundred lines of code.

You have the freedom to do what you will; do what makes *you* happiest and forget the rest is my motto and advice.